# WLResourceRequest result - difference between responseText and responseJSON

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I've spent a couple of hours trying to find out why I only get one row out of many in backend.

The backend is easy enough, it just returns 5 mock JSON objects.

Here is my code to call the IBM MobileFirst platform 8 adapter:

```
    var request = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/WorkOrder/getList", WLResourceRequest.GET);
request.send().then((response)=> {
  console.log("data loaded from adapter: " + JSON.stringify(response.responseJSON), response);
  console.log("Response object: " + JSON.stringify(response));      
  this.data=response.responseJSON;
},
(error)=> {
  console.log("Failed to load data: " + JSON.stringify(error), error);
});
```

The resulting response.responseText is:

> "responseText":"[{\"enddate\":\"2017-03-03\",\"description\":\"Test work order 0\",\"id\":1,\"ts\":\"Ban\",\"status\":\"In progress\"},{\"enddate\":\"2017-03-03\",\"description\":\"Test work order 1\",\"id\":2,\"ts\":\"Ban\",\"status\":\"In progress\"},{\"enddate\":\"2017-03-03\",\"description\":\"Test work order 2\",\"id\":3,\"ts\":\"Ban\",\"status\":\"In progress\"},{\"enddate\":\"2017-03-03\",\"description\":\"Test work order 3\",\"id\":4,\"ts\":\"Ban\",\"status\":\"In progress\"},{\"enddate\":\"2017-03-03\",\"description\":\"Test work order 4\",\"id\":5,\"ts\":\"Ban\",\"status\":\"In progress\"}]"

The resulting response.responseJSON is:

> "responseJSON":{"enddate":"2017-03-03","description":"Test work order 0","id":1,"ts":"Ban","status":"In progress"}

Why doesn't responseJSON contain the same array as responseText?

Comment: What is the exact JSON returned by the adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a defect with the SDK and you could open a PMR for an official fix.